# cfselect bind in cfc does not work when I enable Application.cfc

Tags: data-binding, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfselect

I am trying to create a form with 3 select boxes that are bound to a cfc (triple related cfselect). If I remove the Application.cfc, the code runs just fine, the select box gives me the data I need. However, when I add Application.cfc which has cflogin function which requires users to login before they are able to use any page than my triple related select boxes do not work anymore. The select box just doesn't give out any data from the query in the function. It still connects to the function page, because when I change the name on the bind of the cfselect, it will let me know that that function does not exist in the component. I am not sure what I have to do to make the triple related cfselect work with cflogin in place.

I am using ColdFusion 10

I really appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks, Niva

I added the code:
This is code on form

```
<tr valign="top">  
    <td style="color:DarkSeaGreen; font-weight:bold; width=100">Product Type:</td>
    <td width="200">
    <cfselect name="Selproducttype" bind="cfc:groupfnc.getproducttypeid()"
        display="description" value="producttypeid" BindOnLoad="true"/></td></tr>
<tr valign="top">  
    <td style="color:DarkSeaGreen; font-weight:bold; width=100">Vendor:</td>
    <td width="200">
    <cfselect name="Selvendor" bind="cfc:groupfnc.getven({Selproducttype})"
        display="fullname" value="vendorid" BindOnLoad="true"/></td></tr>   

<tr valign="top">  
    <td style="color:DarkSeaGreen; font-weight:bold; width=100">Product:</td>
    <td width="200">

<cfselect name="Selprod" bind="cfc:groupfnc.getprod({Selvendor})"
        display="fullname" value="productid" BindOnLoad="true" /></td></tr>
<tr valign="top">  
    <td style="color:DarkSeaGreen; font-weight:bold; width=100">Sub Product:</td>
    <td width="200">
    <cfselect name="Selsubprod" bind="cfc:groupfnc.Getsub({Selprod})"
        display="fullname" value="productsubid" /></td></tr>
```

Code on component: groupfnc.cfc

```
  <cffunction name="getproducttypeid" access="remote" output="false" returntype="query">
<cfquery name="listproducttype" datasource="xxxxxx">
    Select distinct producttypeid, (Case when producttypeid = '101' then 'Hotel' 
                         when producttypeid='201' then 'optionalTour' 
                         when producttypeid = '301' then 'Transporation' 
                         when producttypeid = '501' then 'MISC'
                         when producttypeid = '601' then 'OTH' end) as description
    From products
</cfquery>
<cfreturn listproducttype />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getven" access="remote" output="false" returntype="Query">
    <cfargument name="Selproducttype" type="any" required="true">
    <cfif ARGUMENTS.Selproducttype EQ "">
    <cfset ARGUMENTS.Selproducttype = '0'>
    </cfif>
    <cfquery name="listven" datasource="xxxxxx">
    SELECT distinct vendors.fullname, vendors.vendorid 
    from vendors, products
    where products.vendorid= vendors.vendorid
    and  products.producttypeid = #ARGUMENTS.Selproducttype#
    ORDER BY fullname
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn listven />
</cffunction>


<cffunction name="getprod" access="remote" output="false" returntype="Query">
    <cfargument name="Selvendor" type="any" required="true">
    <cfif ARGUMENTS.Selvendor EQ "">
    <cfset ARGUMENTS.Selvendor = '0'>
    </cfif>
    <cfquery name="Lstprod" datasource="xxxxxx">
    Select productid, fullname from products
    where vendorid = #ARGUMENTS.Selvendor#
    order by fullname
    </cfquery>
    <!---</cfif>--->
    <cfreturn Lstprod />
</cffunction>    
<cffunction name="Getsub" access="remote" output="false" returntype="Query">
    <cfargument name="Selprod" type="any" required="true">
    <cfif ARGUMENTS.Selprod EQ "">
    <cfset ARGUMENTS.Selprod = '0'>
    </cfif>
    <cfquery name="Lstsubprod" datasource="xxxxxx">
    Select productsubid, fullname from productsubs
    where productid = #ARGUMENTS.Selprod#
    order by fullname
    </cfquery>
    <!---</cfif>--->
    <cfreturn Lstsubprod />
</cffunction>
```

Here is my application.cfc

```
  <cfcomponent> 
   <cfset This.name = "Orders"> 
   <cfset This.Sessionmanagement="True"> 
   <cfset This.loginstorage="session"> 

     <cffunction name="OnRequestStart"> 

       <cfargument name = "request" required="true"/> 
         <cfif IsDefined("Form.logout")> 
          <cflogout> 
        </cfif> 

    <cflogin> 
       <cfif NOT IsDefined("cflogin")> 
         <cfinclude template="loginform.cfm">

          <cfabort> 
       <cfelse> 
        <cfif cflogin.name IS "" OR cflogin.password IS ""> 

            <cfoutput> 
                <h2>You must enter text in both the User Name and Password fields. 
                </h2> 
            </cfoutput> 
              <cfinclude template="loginform.cfm">
            <cfabort> 
        <cfelse> 
            <cfquery name="loginQuery" dataSource="xxxxxx"> 
            SELECT userid, roles 
            FROM logininfo 
            WHERE 
                userid = '#cflogin.name#' 
                AND upassword = '#cflogin.password#' 
            </cfquery> 
            <cfif loginQuery.roles NEQ ""> 
                <cfloginuser name="#cflogin.name#" Password = "#cflogin.password#" 
                    roles="#loginQuery.roles#"> 
            <cfelse> 


                <cfoutput>
                    <H2>Your login information is not valid.<br> 
                    Please Try again</H2> 
                </cfoutput>     
               <cfinclude template="loginform.cfm">  
                <cfabort> 
            </cfif> 
        </cfif>     
      </cfif> 
  </cflogin> 

   <cfif GetAuthUser() NEQ ""> 
     <cfoutput> 

            <form action="securitytest.cfm" method="Post"> 
            <input type="submit" Name="Logout" value="Logout"> 
        </form> 

       </cfoutput> 
  </cfif> 

 </cffunction> 
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: Without code its pretty hard to help you.  What do the browser dev tools show?  The console should show the ajax requests and responses.  I would also suggest that you just stop using cfselect, cfform, etc and just write your own Javascript.  jQuery would make this very easy and you wont have to rely on CF's built in junk.

Comment: Have you looked at Firebug, to introspect the background Ajax request and it's return? Maybe you've defined onRequest() in your application.cfc, but not a onCFCRequest()? Without seeing code, and request/response details, it is difficult to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I added the code. jQuery is new to me and I am not very comfortable with it. I will give jQUery a try when I have more time.

Comment: I haven't use firebug before, I will try it. I don't have much in my Application.cfc, only the function for cflogin that I copy it down from adobe help. Do I need to add something in my Application.cfc?

Comment: OK, so I run the code through Firebug, this is what happen: when I remove the Application.cfc from the server, I run the page, the select section (for example the producttype section), it appears with <select id="selproducttype" name="Selproducttype"> and listed below it is all the options from the query. When I put the Application.cfc back on the server, the select section only has <select id="selproducttype" name="Selproducttype"> without any options.

Comment: Lots of people use the CFLogin tags without issue - so I wouldn't initially be expecting that to be your issue.(it could be - but I doubt it).Can you also post your Application.cfc? - I'd guess that the issue is one of the request related methods.

Comment: I added the Application.cfc

Comment: First, I'll point out that you shouldn't be doing any output in your Application.cfc.  CFCs are for logic, generally, and not for display.  You should really just be doing cflocation redirects or something similar to load the proper page (login form or the requested page).  That said, you still haven't said what the ajax responses look like.  You just say that the select tag has no options.  In Firebug you can look at the ajax requests and see what they are returning, my guess is that your Application.cfc logic is causing those requests to fail.  You would see these on the "Net" tab of Firebug

Comment: I assume you want the response of "get Ajax.js". here is the response:

Comment: The response file is too long so I put on google share doc. this is the link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1QUyEN38uLNdzJjMjhsT1ZvUVE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Because in my Application.cfc has this part:

```
        <form action="securitytest.cfm" method="Post"> 
        <input type="submit" Name="Logout" value="Logout"> 
    </form> 

   </cfoutput>
```

So looking at the ajax response the logout form is placed infornt so the select box didnt parse the value.I removed this partin the Application.cfc and the page run just fine.
Thank you so much for all your help!
^_^